# Use of "sparse categorical cross entropy"

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am having problem understanding why sparse categorical cross entropy does not work for SVHN dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np

train = loadmat('data/train_32x32.mat')
test = loadmat('data/test_32x32.mat')

x_train = train['X']
y_train = train['y']
x_train = x_train.astype('float64')
y_train = y_train.astype('int64')

x_test = test['X']
x_test = x_test.astype('float64')
y_test = test['y']
y_test = y_test.astype('int64')

# reorder data
x_train = np.moveaxis(x_train, -1, 0)
x_test = np.moveaxis(x_test, -1, 0)
def colored_to_gray(x):
    '''
    input shape: n_sample, n_x, x_y, n_channel
    output shape: n_sample, n_x, x_y, 1
    this is a rudementary way of converting a colored image into gray image
    '''
    x = np.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return x

def normalize_data(x):
    '''
    normalize data so that values are between 0 to 1
    '''
    x = x / 255.0
    return x

x_train = colored_to_gray(x_train)
x_test = colored_to_gray(x_test)

x_train = normalize_data(x_train)
x_test = normalize_data(x_test)
print("Shape of Training Data: {}".format(x_train.shape))
print("Shape of Training Labels: {}".format(y_train.shape))
print("Shape of Testing Data: {}".format(x_test.shape))
print("Shape of Testing Labels: {}".format(y_test.shape))

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential([
    Flatten(name='Flatten_Input', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]),
    Dense(units=1024, activation='relu', name='Dense_1'),
    Dense(units=512, activation='relu', name='Dense_2'),
    Dense(units=256, activation='relu', name='Dense_3'),
    Dense(units=32, activation='relu', name='Dense_4'),
    Dense(units=10, activation='softmax', name='Output')
])

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=256)
```

with this model.fit calling, I was expecting it work on 10 classes and train. instead I got 'nan' as loss output and 0 for accuracy.

- Can someone explain what is happening here?
- is it related to the size of the input or to the type of the input?

Thanks,

Comment: Well if your true labels are integer values then use Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy. Could you print out ```x_train.shape[1:]```?

Comment: @yudhiesh, 
shape of training data:(73257, 32, 32, 1)
shape of label: (73257, 1)

I tried:
- squeezing 
            * input only, 
            * input and labels, 
            * labels only, 
- converting to integer
            * input only, 
            * input and labels, 
            * labels only
neither of those approaches worked

Answer (score 1):

`Sparse` is when each image belongs to ONE class only. In the SVHN dataset it is not, for example the image `321` has `3, 2` and `1`, which is multiclass. Change it to `categorical_crossentropy` and it should work. Moreover, you are not using Accuracy as metric.

Comment: If you're going to use ```categorical_crossentropy``` the data has to be one-hot encoded firstly.

Comment: @AerysS The problem is "multilabel".

Comment: @yudhiesh, you are right but since the problem is already mutilabel and so the y_hat is already arranged in one-hot fashion unlike multiclass problems, the solution suggested by AerysS will work.

Comment: SVHN is not multi-label, it is a standard multi-class classification

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, you are right. SVHN is not multilabel. it "should" be standard multi class classification, but it does not work. To check my mindset I tested using MATLAB, it works (all I had to do was converting the class values to categorical array). That's why this does not makes sense to me at all!